# measure of boundary of unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've seen some solutions to this problem but I'm wondering what is incorrect about an argument like this:

$S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: |x| = 1\}$, then $\delta S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: |\delta x| = 1\}$, and so

\begin{align*}
\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d: |\delta ||x| = 1\} & = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d: |x| = 1 / |\delta | \}
\end{align*}

As we take $\delta $ large, then $\delta S$ becomes the set in which $|x| = 0$, i.e. the origin in $\mathbb{R}^d$ , which has zero measure, and since: $m(\delta S) = \delta^d m(S)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, it follows that $m(S) = 0$

Comment: Note that the equality you wrote is not correct. Indeed
$$
\delta S = \{\delta x : x \in S\} = \{\delta x : |x| = 1\} = \{y : |y| = |\delta|\}.
$$
So $\delta S$ is the sphere with radius $|\delta|$.

Comment: In fact, it is correct that the $d$-dimensional measure of the $d-1$-dimensional sphere $S$ is zero.  But your nonsense argument does not prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\delta S$ is for any $\delta>0$ a sphere with radius $\delta>0$. No matter how big $\delta >0$ is choosen, it does not become the set $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 3):

The argument you give is wrong, as already noted. One *can* show that $m(S)=0$ by considering the sets $\delta S$.

For example, say $(\delta_j)\subset(1,2)$ and $\delta_j\ne\delta_k$ for $j\ne k$. Let $$A=\bigcup_j\delta_j S.$$ Then $$m(\delta_j S)=\delta_j^n m(S)\ge m(S);$$since the $\delta_j  S$ are disjoint, if $m(S)>0$ this would show that $m(A)=\infty$, which is false since $A$ is bounded.

(Here of course I'm taking $\delta S=\{\delta x:x\in S\}$ as usual...)

Comment: Sorry to comment so long after the posting. This doesn't seem right. If $\delta_j\in(0,1)$ then so is $\delta_j^n$ so $\delta_j^nm(S)<m(S)$, not $\geq$. However, if you take $\delta_j=j^{-1/n}$, then $\sum_{j=1}^\infty\delta_j^n=\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^{-1}=\infty$ so $m(A)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\delta_j^nm(S)=\infty$, and the proof concludes as in the comment.

Comment: @JeffRubin Whoops, thx. One can salvage the complete triviality of the argument by just saying $\delta_j\in(1,2)$. (Using $\sum 1=\infty$ is less deep than $\sum 1/j=\infty$???)